# String greater than floating number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers

I have something like this

```
var str = "3.0";
```

I'm checking like condition following, it's working fine,  JS auto converting string into a floating number and giving the expected result.

Is this practice fine or any side effects. I always receive string like 1.0 / 2.0 / 3.0 / 4.0 etc

```
if(str > 2.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's ok to do that if the value `2.0` is always hardcoded. Since you can also compare with the greater operator strings like `"a" < "b"` returns `true`

If that's not the case, I would explicitly convert the string value to `Number`

Answer (score 0):

try to cast str to number with + operator

`if(+str > 2.0`)